# find the reoccurrence of subset of matrix in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, data-structures

I have a scenario where the matrix input is, 5*5

```
4 4 4 1 1
4 4 4 0 2
4 4 4 5 1
4 4 4 2 3
4 4 4 4 4
```

If I give any input like 2*3 or 3*3, it should find the reoccurrences of the matrix. like

3*3

it has the subsets of matrix like this

from row 1;-

```
4 4 4 
4 4 4
4 4 4
```

likewise, If I specify 3 * 3 the subset of the matrix has 3 occurrences. Is it possible to convert this to Python?

[image: Reoccurrence image]

Comment: Must you start gfrom top left corner?

Comment: yes correct start from left @KU99

Answer (score 1):

Say your original 5x5 matrix is called `input_matrix`. You could do this to find the number of times a given submatrix from top-left repeats:

```
input_size = input_matrix.shape[0]

# However many rows and columns the sub-matrix should have.
num_rows = 3
num_cols = 3

# The sub-matrix to find the number of occurrences of.
orig_matrix = input_matrix[:num_rows, :num_cols]

num_occurrences = 0

# Iterate through all indices at positions where the sub-matrix could still fit 
# inside the input matrix.
for row_num in range(input_size - num_rows + 1):
    for col_num in range(input_size - num_cols + 1):

      # Get the sub-matrix at those indices
      this_matrix = input_matrix[row_num:row_num + num_rows, col_num:col_num + num_cols]

      # Get the difference between the original sub-matrix and the current submatrix.
      # If difference at all points is 0, the submatrices are the same.
      if np.count_nonzero(orig_matrix - this_matrix, axis=None) == 0:
          num_occurrences += 1
```

`num_occurrences` contains the number you want. I'm sure there are more efficient ways to do this, but here's what I've got.